# Two enum constants in Kotlin with the same value

Tags: kotlin, enums

Is it possible to create an 'alias' for an enum constant in Kotlin, so that its possible to refer to one single enum constant by two names?

Eg: If `MyEnum` is the name of the enum with 2 constants `A1` and `A2`, then `MyEnum.B1` should effectively be the same as `MyEnum.A1` and `MyEnum.B2` should effectively be the same as `MyEnum.A2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply by including the 'alias' names as static `val`s inside the enum.

```
enum class MyEnum {
    A1, A2;

    companion object {
        val B1 = A1
        val B2 = A2
    }
}
```